# Desktop recording software with keypressing hints

Tags: software-recommendation, video, desktop-recording

I am looking for a desktop recording application like [democreator](http://www.wondershare.com/pro/democreator.html), which can automatically create tool tips of the input key pressed in the video being recorded. For example, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will create a tooltip like "Entered Alt+Tab" and so on.

**The Question is:** Is there something equivalent to that for Ubuntu? I don't want to use Windows software via Wine.

**Update:** One answerer mentions keymon. Thanks. But it was not what I was looking for. Keymon runs on the screen blocking some area, and I wanted a tooltip like feature to be displayed in the video only.

Comment: Have a look at [Record My Desktop](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/record-your-desktop-sessions-in-ubuntu-linux-with-recordmydesktop/), and let me know

Comment: @Mitch, It does not include the key presses on the video.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [key-mon](https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon) with recordmydesktop.

```
sudo apt install keymon
```

Or maybe [Screenkey](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey), initially based on the key-mon project. You can install Screenkey with

```
sudo apt install screenkey
```