# I want to have multiple active applications that will all simultaneously receive keystrokes

Tags: keyboard

I am trying to display my keystrokes on a keyboard monitoring application while I am interacting with another application. The problem is that the keyboard monitoring application doesn't receive my keystrokes unless it is the active window, but if the keyboard monitoring application is the active window then the other application that I need to be interacting with doesn't receive keystrokes because now THAT application isn't active. I recorded a video showing what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72j_Um_6j6o

So I need to somehow get the keystrokes to register with multiple applications. I don't care how this is done. Make two programs be active simultaneously? Get the keyboard input to register with a specific application even if it isn't active? How would I go about doing any of this? [This application](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) seems to be outputting keystrokes to multiple terminal windows, but I'm not sure if it extends to any application. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: `keymon` does that; It always stays on top and captures any mouse clicks and key strokes. [This old answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/161139/37165) has suggested that and `screenkey`.

Comment: Yes, I know about keymon. Unfortunately, it isn't useful for my purposes. I need certain keys to be present at all times and highlighted when I click them -- keymon only has that functionality for shift, alt, meta, control, and mouse. The way it is set up makes my keypresses incomprehensible to convey what I am doing.

Comment: My bad, I got confused with the keyboard monitoring application. Then, you must be looking for something like [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) or [`mango-lassi`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mango-lassi&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).